# Get at a Google Map object from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get the Map object(s) for a page that has one or more Google Maps on it, in Chrome at least?

I want to get access, from a Google Chrome extension, to any Google Maps that are on the current page.

...or is there a good reason why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found out a way to do this on the Google Maps JavaScript API group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/lPydWBYe1kQ/discussion